# Is there a way to read the coordinate information from zone.tab using Linux command line or C++

Tags: c++, linux, geolocation, timezone

I need to approximate geolocation coordinates of an embedded linux device based soley on its timezone. This is a stand alone device which is not connected to the inetrnet and therefore must only use data stored on the local filesystem.

The [zone.tab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Zone.tab) database stores coordinate information (Lattitude & Longitude) for the principal city in each timezone, however I have not found an easy interface to read these using c++.

PHP provides an interface [DateTimeZone::getLocation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getlocation.php) to access this information.  Is there a C++ or Linux system interface to do the same?

Obviuosly I can write my own interface which reads the file and converts the data, but I would prefer to implement a more standardised solution.

Comment: PHP is open-source, you can always download its source and look how the `DateTimeZone::getLocation` function implements it.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux systems, the `zone.tab` file is deployed to `/usr/share/zoneinfo`, where programs like `tzselect` use it directly.  It is not exposed through a common OS-level API.

PHP does not use this information.  It has its own tzdata compiler, and includes the zone info (including zone.tab) in the timezonedb bundle - which is embedded in each release of PHP, or [can be downloaded separately from PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb).  Unless you are already shipping PHP with your system, you probably don't want to get it from here.

Ultimately, if you don't have `/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab` on your machine, and you need access to it, then you should get it from [the tzdata distribution](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) directly.

But seriously - getting lat/lon of a device based on what the user of the device picked for a time zone is going to be just asking for trouble.  Keep in mind that the geographical region of a time zone can span hundreds or thousands of miles from its point of reference.  Also, there are plenty of administrative zones that have no fixed location reference (such as `Etc/GMT+2`).  Not every valid time zone is in zone.tab.

Comment: Thanks - PHP is currently shipped with the product and we do need to manually synchronise the PHP timezone to the system timezone. We will be changing it from PHP to node.js in the future. This functionality is to provide a fallback for customers who do not know their lat/long as our sales department have said that it is unreasonable to expect them to manually enter their location.  They currently enter in a timezone which we would use to provide default lat/long which the customer can refine.  Maybe for the time being I'll call a php script from the C++ application which returns the lat/long.